# Why don't I get the expected count of nodes on each degree of separation?

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I have data that is set up like that

```
(Employee)-[:MANAGES]->(Employee)
```

It is strictly hierarchical, i.e., every employee has only one manager, there is a single boss at the top.

When I do

```
MATCH (e:Employee) RETURN count(e)
```

I get **4197**. Then, when I do

```
MATCH 
  p=(e:Employee)<-[m:MANAGES*]-(:Employee {id: 'x'})
WITH 
  count(e) as people,
  length(p) as distance
RETURN people, distance
ORDER BY distance DESC
```

With **x** being the top boss, I get a list that looks like this:

```
╔═══════════╦═════════╗
║ DISTANCE  ║ PEOPLE  ║
╠═══════════╬═════════╣
║  1        ║    24   ║
║  2        ║   152   ║
║  3        ║   698   ║
║  4        ║  2019   ║
║  5        ║  3275   ║
║  6        ║  1942   ║
║  7        ║   117   ║
╚═══════════╩═════════╝
```

(btw, I get the same result for distance 5 when I change the asterisk being MANAGES to ***5**)

The sum is clearly more than the total, so somehow stuff is counted double - and that is the question. I am obviously suffering from a misunderstanding with regard to what is happening

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Edited for clarity. - *ed.*] You need to add the `DISTINCT` keyword to your `COUNT` aggregation statement.

```
MATCH p = (e:Employee)<-[:MANAGES*]-(:Employee {id: 'x'})
WITH LENGTH(p) as distance, COUNT(DISTINCT e) as people,
RETURN people, distance
ORDER BY distance DESC
```

You are getting caught by some deep voodoo in the automatic de-duplication that goes along with aggregations because there are multiple paths to your chosen endpoints (the employees). Matching on a path pattern will find you paths to employees, then assign node & relationship aliases based on that path. There's no way to locate a group of individual nodes (employees) besides matching a property or ensuring in your schema that you don't ever have alternate routes, **or** (much better) using a combination of pathfinding and `DISTINCT`. This example below makes it a little clearer, though it's slower and potentially destructive of information:

```
MATCH (boss:Employee {id:'x'})
WITH boss
MATCH (e:Employee)<-[:MANAGES*]-(boss)
WITH DISTINCT e, boss
MATCH path = shortestPath( (e) <- [:MANAGES*] - (boss) )
RETURN length(path) AS distance, COUNT(e)
```

So this just locates all the employees that do fall somewhere under the boss, ensures (with `DISTINCT`) that each one is only carried forward in a single row (no duplicates), then for each employee, finds *only* the shortest path to the boss. Now you have a guaranteed single path per employee, so when you aggregate and count, you only get 1 count per person.

Now, if you had "sideways" hierarchical relationships before (an employee had multiple paths *of different lengths* that led to them), this method and the above will yield different numbers. The `DISTINCT` in the first example made sure it counted only distinct employees *at a specific distance from the boss*, so the same employee could appear in multiple rows. The second example, though slower, applies `DISTINCT` to the whole group of potential employees first, and then only counts them for their shortest route to management, which does lose some data, but ensures a consistent total. You can consider which one is appropriate for your use.

Comment: Thank you - the second option worked correctly, while the first statement (just adding distinct) does not.

Comment: It worked exactly correctly, it just isn't asking the question you want to ask. See the note about the `sideways` hierarchy. The first query asks "how many employees *can* be X steps from the boss", while the second says "what's the single shortest way for each employee X to get back to the boss".

Answer (score 0):

That's puzzling. My guess is there may be a data problem you're not aware of. I'm assuming ids are uniquely constrained, so as a sanity check, try this query to see if people are being counted twice:

```
MATCH 
  (e:Employee)<-[m:MANAGES*]-(:Employee {id: 'x'})
WITH e, count(e) as occurrences
RETURN e, occurrences 
WHERE occurrences > 1
ORDER BY occurrences DESC
```

If there are some being counted twice, you may need to check for employees that are managed by more than one person, which would cause them to be counted multiple times in your query:

```
MATCH (e:Employee)
WITH e, SIZE( (e)<-[:MANAGES]-(:Employee) ) as managers
RETURN e, managers 
WHERE managers > 1
ORDER BY managers DESC
```